# 401 Error when batching on Gmail API, but not during individual GET calls (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

I am trying to implement batching for my GET calls in javascript, so that I can it up when running. I am running into a 401 error when using the batch (code shown below along with the error), but when I ran individual GET calls, there was no error, and I already connected through OAUTH2 Is there an issue with how I am constructing the body for my batch? Any help would be appreciated!

```
var part1 = '--batch_boundary\nContent-Type: application/http\n\Content-ID: '
  var part2 = '\nGET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/'
  var body = ''
  var numChunks = Math.ceil(messages.length / 100);
  for (var i = 0; i < numChunks; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 100; j++) {
      if (100i + (j-1) < messages.length - 1) {
        body = body + part1 + j + '\n' + part2 + messages[100i + (j-1)].id + API_KEY + '\n\n';
      }
    }
    body = body + '--batch_boundary--'

    console.log(body);

    BATCHED = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_boundary",
        Authorization: "Bearer" + token,
      },
      method: "POST",
      body: body,
    };

    const msgData = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/batch/gmail/v1", BATCHED);
    console.log(await msgData.text())

    body = '';
  }
```

ERROR:

```
--batch_IS59KYdZ1ozjuM1r9SLqUDDV-Ejv2wMM
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-1

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/"
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that!

Comment: Can you post the answer/what worked for you? This may save other users who encounter the same issue from spending time looking for the answer :) @btw516

Comment: Definitely, once I find a solution, I'll post it!

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant you already found the solution! Which type of credentials are you using? How does the body for one of the requests look like? Also, have you tried using `"Authorization": "Bearer " + token,` instead?